# Weka analysis and predictions

Tags: data-mining, weka, data-analysis

i am doing this project that has several inputs and several outputs at the same time.
is there a way to do a prediction for more than 1 class at the same time in Weka?
any help is highly appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning,

Weka only supports single class attributes. However, untested, I think you may be able to work around this. Try the following, I'm interested as to what kind of accuracy you get.

eg data.

```
BloodIron    real
BloodSuger   real
BloodColor   real
Diabetes     bool    class
Lifespan     real    class
```

Using the data above, train to solve only the 'Diabetes' class. Once you have the variables enter them into your dataset and use them to solve your second 'LifeSpan' class attribute.

To increase accuracy solve the class variable with the highest entropy first.

Comment: thank you very much, i am going to try that :)

Comment: it is not possible to predict both outputs at the same time?